# Where are Lenny ISOs now that Squeeze is out?

Tags: debian, iso, download

So the next stable version of Debian is out but I need to install the previous one (Lenny) because my VPS is running that version. I haven't been able to find an «official» download link for Lenny's ISOs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Debian CD FAQ on old images](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#old).